# ddply skipping empty dataframe

Tags: r, plyr

I try to get the empirical distribution for different levels of a factor from a sample.

For some reason, running the following :

```
  a <- daply(caseDataset, x, nrow) / nrow(caseDataset)
```

gives me some NA for the cases where the dataset has no values for a level of the factor x
So I have to use override the result with

```
  a[is.na(a)] <- 0
```

How can I force daply to have a uniform behavior (and pass the empty dataframe down to nrow) ?

Sample for caseDataset:

```
dataset <- data.frame(
  a1     = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE),
  a2     = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
  a3     = c(1,6,5,4,7,3,8,7,5),
  target = c('+','+','-','+','-','-','-','+','-'))

caseDataset <- subset(dataset, target=='-')

daply(caseDataset, "target", nrow)
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the behavior, but you can do this with base R: a`prop.table(table(caseDataset$x))`

Comment: can you post a sample of `caseDataset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `.drop_i` switch do what you are after?

```
> daply(caseDataset, "target", nrow, .drop_i=FALSE)
- + 
5 0
```